# Is there anyway to provide click listener to slider layout in daimajia AndroidImageSlider?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-sliding

In my project there is an image slider done by [daimajia AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) . When i click on image i want to open another activity/page. I have tried and inserted an linearlayout inside the sliderlayout. But click listener in this linearlayout makes sliderlayout stuck.

```
<com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
            android:id="@+id/advertiseSlider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/linearSlider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            </com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have not tested this code properly but it goes something like this:

```
SliderLayout mySliderLayout = (SliderLayout) findViewById(R.id.slider);
for (int i = 0; i < item.getImages().size(); i++) {
  BaseSliderView baseSliderView = new BaseSliderView(context) {
    @Override public View getView() {
      View v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_slider, null);
      ImageView target = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.daimajia_slider_image);
      bindEventAndShow(v, target);
      return v;
    }
  };
  baseSliderView.image(item.getImages().get(i));
  baseSliderView.setOnSliderClickListener(new BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener() {
    @Override public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {
      Log.d("MyActivity", "index selected:" + mySliderLayout.getCurrentPosition());
    }
  });
  mySliderLayout.addSlider(baseSliderView);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a really old question but I thought I comment.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    SliderLayout mySliderLayout = (SliderLayout) findViewById(R.id.slider);

    HashMap<String, Integer> image_maps = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    image_maps.put("Title1", R.drawable.slide1);
    image_maps.put("Title2", R.drawable.slide2);
    image_maps.put("Title3", R.drawable.slide3);

    for (String name : image_maps.keySet())
    {
        TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);
        textSliderView
            .description(name)
            .image(image_maps.get(name))
            .setOnSliderClickListener(this);
        textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
        textSliderView.getBundle()
            .putString("extra", name);
        sliderShow.addSlider(textSliderView);
    }
    sliderShow.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Accordion);
    sliderShow.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
    sliderShow.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
    sliderShow.setDuration(10000);
}

public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView sliderview)
{
    Intent myNewIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyNewActivity.class);
    startActivity(myNewIntent);
}
```

I hope it is useful to anyone :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
SliderLayout sliderLayout = (SliderLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.advertiseSlider);
final List<String> listUrls = allImageUrlList();

for(int index = 0; index <listUrls.size(); index++){
            DefaultSliderView defaultSliderView = new DefaultSliderView(mContext);
            final int finalI = index;
            defaultSliderView.image(urls.get(index))
                              .setOnSliderClickListener(new BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Image.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("imageurls", urls.get(finalI));
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                  }
                              });

sliderLayout.addSlider(defaultSliderView);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution. First you need to implements `BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener` in you activity.

It will provide the following override method,

```
@Override
public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),slider.getBundle().get("extra") + "",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Make sure you have added the onClickListener to you slider as below,

```
 DefaultSliderView textSliderView = new DefaultSliderView(getContext());
        textSliderView
                .image("")
                .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                .setOnSliderClickListener(this);
```